# Binding variable to table name with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm using cx_Oracle in Python and can't get a variable be used as table name, like in this simple example:

```
query = "select * from some.:usertable.userinfo"

bindvars = {'usertable':usertable}

cursor.execute(query, bindvars)
```

What is the correct syntax? Variable substition works fine when I use `WHERE`… etc. but not with table names. I guess I have to separate ":usertable" somehow…

Comment: Database adapters rarely support using parameters for anything that isn't a 'value' (something that needs quoting). Either use string formatting (dodgy, you run the risk of a sql injection) or use a library like SQLAlchemy that let's you produce valid SQL using Python code.

Comment: @septi:I think using table name as bind variable is not possible ,you need to create a dynamic statement ,by appending the table name to youe select statement.

Comment: OK thank's, at least I can stop wasting my time ;-) Could you add an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database adapters rarely support using parameters for anything that isn't a 'value' (something that needs quoting). Either use string formatting (dodgy, you run the risk of a sql injection) or use a library like SQLAlchemy that let's you produce valid SQL using Python code.

If you are certain your `usertable` value is sane (checked against a list of existing table names, for example), the following would work:

```
query = 'select * from some.{usertable}.userinfo'.format(usertable=usertable)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind an object name in Oracle, only a literal. Oracle does, however, have an inbuilt package [`dbms_assert`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_assert.htm), to help prevent SQL injection when using dynamic object names. The most useful function in your case is probably [`sql_object_name`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_assert.htm#BABDDEEF), which:

> "... verifies that the input parameter string is a qualified SQL
>   identifier of an existing SQL object."

For instance you could do the following in cx_Oracle.

```
object_name = cursor.callfunc('sys.dbms_assert.sql_object_name'
                             , cx_Oracle.string, ['usertable'])
```

It raises ORA-44002, if the name is invalid, which you [can capture in cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html#exceptions), or if everything's fine continue as Martijn has suggested.

I would recommend reading Oracle's guide to [guarding against SQL injection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BJECFFHD).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a bit late to reply, but I was dealing with the same thing 2 days ago.

The solution is, as Martjin says, to format the query.

```
query = f'select * from {tableName}'
```

Hope it helps someone as it helped me.